# What kind of matrix transformations are allowed in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

In special relativity, one can transform a 4-vector as follows:

$$
x'=\Lambda x
$$

Of course in this case, $\Lambda$ cannot be an arbitrary $4\times 4$ matrix of $\mathbb{M}(4,\mathbb{C})$. For instance, it must invertible. I believe, technically, it must be an element spawned by the basis representation of $O(3,1)$...?

For general relativity, if I am to express a transformation $x'=Gx$ where $G$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix, what are the restrictions on $G$ such that one can claim the transformation is consistent with general relativity. Is it the case that since general relativity is not a group, then it follows that any $G$ (or almost any $G$) is permitted?

edit:

Furthermore, it seems that since GR is non-linear, and the general linear group is the most general matrix group, then it follows that $G$ must be an element of $\mathbb{M}(4,\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 0):

GR is invariant under diffeomorphisms, i.e. (up to subtleties) any smooth change of coordinates

$$x^\mu \to x'^\mu = x'^\mu(x)$$

This can be non-linear and it definitely includes the Minkowski group as a subgroup.

Comment: So in terms of matrices, diffeomorphism admits a representation via an infinitesimal jacobian matrix? So the matrices are not even in $M(4,C)$, but must include infinitesimals as elements, right?